# ffmpeg - Prevent ffmpeg to skip frames

Tags: ffmpeg, effects

I am trying to move a png image by 10px over a white background during 2s (fps=25), but the transition I got is not smooth.

Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync passthrough -f lavfi -i color=c=white:size=300x250 -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=eval=frame:format=yuv444:x=120:y=lerp(100\,110\,t/2)[s1]" -map "[s1]"  -c:v libx264 -t 2 video.mp4 -hide_banner -loglevel debug
```

At first I thought that all decimals were rounded to integers, but from what I see in the logs it seems that ffmpeg skips frames that contain a fraction of a pixel as a `y` coordinate *(i.e. 100.2)*.

Here is the [generated video](https://local-banners.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/video.mp4) & [the log file.](https://local-banners.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/log.txt)

Is there a way to generate a smooth effect?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg does not do sub-pixel overlay. Computed co-ordinates are truncated to integers.

The closest to getting a smooth result is to overlay a large PNG on a large background and then downscale the result to the final resolution i.e. `[largebg][largefg]overlay=...,scale=300:250:flags=bicubic`

Comment: do you know if using `overlay_cuda` (gpu) supports sub-pixels?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: I tried: Scaling by 4, but the result is blurry. Can you think of another way to get the best quality? ```ffmpeg -y  -vsync 0 -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:size=300x250" -f lavfi -i "color=color=black@0.0:size=1200x1000,format=yuva420p" -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[2]scale=228:136[s0];[1][s0]overlay=eof_action=repeat:eval=frame:format=yuv444:x=480:y=lerp(400\,440\,t/2)[s1];[s1]scale=300x250:flags=bicubic[s2];[0][s2]overlay[s3]" -map "[s3]" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 2 video_scale.mp4 -hide_banner```